# File_get_content . Failed to open a stream

Tags: php

I am a PHP apprentice. And I have a problem I can not solve with my meager knowledge. Indeed, I want to open a page just by submitting my form. And every time I receive this message: "failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly......". Would there be a reason for that? I remind you that I am fairly new to the language. This is my code :

My "You page" :

```
<?php
$query=file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrqDqqy8Yok');
echo($query);
?>
```

And my form is just calling this page.

This is the entire answer when i want to submit my form :

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiFrfeJ8dKM): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\stpnet\You.php on line 2

Comment: I think there's a firewall blocking connections from your server to YouTube.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. But, I have the same answer even if I'm just going to google.com. There would not be a configuration in the xampp or something?

Comment: Can someone help me ?

Comment: There's a configuration option that blocks URLs in `file_get_contents`, but that would cause a different error. Something on your server or network is blocking connections to web sites/

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure that it is an firewall problem. I have testet your code and it's working for me.
Or maybe you can try to set the [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) in the php.ini file (but that would be another error message).

Answer (score 0):

try to follow this code hopefully it will work.

```
  $query= file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrqDqqy8Yok",true)
```